# Create an individual variable conditionally

Tags: r, database, loops

Here is a subset of the dataset I have.

```
 Date      Time     Period          Server   Subject    Indiv
 1004        9          1            1         1        NA
 1004        9          1            1         2        NA
 1004        9          1            2         1        NA
 1004        9          1            2         2        NA 
 1004        9          2            1         1        NA
 1004        9          2            1         2        NA
 1004        9          2            2         1        NA
 1004        9          2            2         2        NA
 1004        13         1            1         1        NA
 1004        13         1            1         2        NA
 1004        13         1            2         1        NA
 1004        13         1            2         2        NA  
 1004        13         2            1         1        NA
 1004        13         2            1         2        NA
 1004        13         2            2         1        NA
 1004        13         2            2         2        NA
```

This dataset is extracted from an economic experiment. It means that we ran some sessions on April 10th, at 9 and 13. The game they played contained 2 periods and they played on two different server because of different treatments.
In this subset, we have 8 different individuals (in the real one, I have 96).
Subject 1 from the first line, is also the same from the fifth, because he played at 9, and was on the server 1. But he is not the same than the one who played on server 2 (line 3 and 7).

So I'd like to create an "individual variable" to identify each subject and create a panel dataset (but my abilities in programmation are limited).

Here is an overview of the result I'd like to have for all my 96 individuals.

```
 Date      Time     Period          Server   Subject    Indiv
 1004        9          1            1         1        1
 1004        9          1            1         2        2
 1004        9          1            2         1        3
 1004        9          1            2         2        4
 1004        9          2            1         1        1
 1004        9          2            1         2        2
 1004        9          2            2         1        3
 1004        9          2            2         2        4
 1004        13         1            1         1        5
 1004        13         1            1         2        6
 1004        13         1            2         1        7
 1004        13         1            2         2        8  
 1004        13         2            1         1        5
 1004        13         2            1         2        6
 1004        13         2            2         1        7
 1004        13         2            2         2        8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution using the `data.table` package might be:

```
library(data.table)
df$Indiv <- as.integer(df$Indiv)
setDT(df)[, Indiv := .GRP, by = .(Time, Server, Subject)]

df
#    Date Time Period Server Subject Indiv
# 1: 1004    9      1      1       1     1
# 2: 1004    9      1      1       2     2
# 3: 1004    9      1      2       1     3
# 4: 1004    9      1      2       2     4
# 5: 1004    9      2      1       1     1
# 6: 1004    9      2      1       2     2
# 7: 1004    9      2      2       1     3
# 8: 1004    9      2      2       2     4
# 9: 1004   13      1      1       1     5
#10: 1004   13      1      1       2     6
#11: 1004   13      1      2       1     7
#12: 1004   13      1      2       2     8
#13: 1004   13      2      1       1     5
#14: 1004   13      2      1       2     6
#15: 1004   13      2      2       1     7
#16: 1004   13      2      2       2     8
```

Or if you prefer `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df$Indiv <- df %>% group_indices(Time, Server, Subject)
```